# Adding a file generated by jenkins in SVN

Tags: jenkins, tortoisesvn

My selenium webdriver test script generates screenshot. we run scripts through jenkins. I wanna these screenshots to be updated in SVN every time the scripts are run in jenkins. How can i achieve it?

Comment: The results of automated tests normally shouldn't be put in your code repository in the first place. Put them in another location where you track your other built artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to checkout the [Jenkins SVN Publisher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SVN+Publisher).  It should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the repository for the images the the list of repos in the source control block, and the add a shell script to "svn add" and "svn commit" (you must have a command line svn tool on your path, if you're using windows, check out http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download